# expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT

Tags: angular, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

i´v tryed to get and maven project with an spring module and an angular module to run. but as i edited the poms(like shown here https://dzone.com/articles/simplified-building-web-application-using-spring-b), it gives me the error in the title. im programming in IntelliJ Communety

the poms are:
main project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <modules>media-backend</modules>
   <modules>media-frontend</modules>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/>
   </parent>
   <groupId>neyt</groupId>
   <artifactId>media</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>Mediathek</name>
   <description>MediathekProject</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
      <node.version>v18.12.1</node.version>
      <npm.version>9.2.0</npm.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
         <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
         <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

backend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <parent>
      <artifactId>media</artifactId>
      <groupId>neyt</groupId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
         <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
         <version>23.0.0</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <artifactId>media-backend</artifactId>
   <properties>
      <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

frontend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <parent>
  <artifactId>media</artifactId>
  <groupId>neyt</groupId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <artifactId>media-frontend</artifactId>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory>
     <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
     <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
     <nodeDownloadRoot>http://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
     <npmDownloadRoot>http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
     <installDirectory>./</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>install node and npm</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>npm install</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <arguments>ci --loglevel=error</arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>build frontend</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

[moduls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuLED.png)
[Artefacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODBse.png)

dose anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: The modules parts seemed to be wrong. Starting with `<modules><module>first</module></modules>`.. please check that...

Comment: Your xml is invalid. The error message indicates you have text where a tag was expected.

Comment: thank you so much @khmarbaise. feel a bit dump that i didnt realized

Comment: The error message tells you the exact. line and file of the error location... ;-) Just fine happens from time to time.